# Display ethernet interface and its corresponding IP address from Linux "ip a s"

Tags: linux, awk, ip, ip-address, ethernet

I am trying to list all the ethernet device names and its assigned IP address available in the RHEL node using the output of **ip addr show** command

I print all the network interfaces names only with the following:

```
ip a s | awk -F: '/^[^ ]/ {print $2}'
```

I am trying to get the output in the below format by applying more logic and coding in the above **awk** command (or anything preferably **sed** or **perl** possibly a one-liner):

```
eth0: 10.xx.xx.xx
eth1: 172.xx.xx.xx
```

Also, loopback **lo** device has to be ignored in the output as this output goes to ansible inventory file after verification

Comment: Could you please post sample output of command `ip a s` once(with sample IPs off course) and let us know the sample expected output too as per that, which will help us to understand the question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```sh
ip --oneline addr show
```

which should be reasonably convenient to parse with Awk.

```sh
ip --oneline addr show | awk '$3 == "inet" && $2 != "lo" { print $2 ": " $4 }
```

Maybe see also `ip --brief` which is even more compact.

For more advanced usage, there is also `ip --json addr show` which outputs very detailed information about all interfaces in JSON format.  See also [the `ip` manual page.](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html)

Comment: For more, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216101/ip-addr-in-one-line-per-interface

Comment: Amazing! thank you for the solution and the link. I knocked-off the `/CIDR` after the IP address: `ip -o a s | awk '$3 == "inet" && $2 != "lo" {print $2 ": " $4}' | sed 's/\/.*//'`

Comment: Adding -f inet or -4 to the ip command removes the need for $3 == "inet" in the awk command

Comment: Awk is perfectly able to do anything `sed` can do; you probably want `sub(/\/.*/, "", $4)`